# How do I highlight the menu for a child page?

Tags: theme-development, menus

EDIT: This used to be

> How do I force a page to be
>   `is_archive == true`?

I was trying to solve the wrong problem. Instead of forcing the post/page to have a particular attribute, I should have looked at the classes applied to the menu item. The 'Blog' menu-item has the `current-page-ancestor` class applied to it. I can style the menu based on this.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have my own theme where I created an `archives.php` template in order to have a page that tries to list the different ways to view archives and to give a place for users to browse the archives if they want to.

I created a page using the WP admin page and I made it's parent the 'Blog' page. The 'Blog' page is the page where all my posts get emitted. I have a menu at the top and right now, every sub-page under the 'Blog' page causes the menu to highlight 'Blog' (this is the correct behavior). Specifically, the menu item has the style `current_page_*` applied to it. This doesn't happen when you load `blog/archives` (the template/page I created in the first paragraph).

So when I click on the date of a blog post, it brings me to an archived post page it looks like this (note that the Blog menu item is highlighted):

[image: Archived Date Posts]

When I go to my archives, it looks like this (note that the menu item is NOT highlighted):

[image: Archives Page]

I looked at `$wp_query` to see what the difference was. I saw that `is_archive` or `is_home` was true in the cases where the menu-item was correctly styled.

How do I force my page to be `is_archive == true`? I tried to insert a `$wp_query->set('is_archive', 1);` before the call to `get_header();` in my template but that didn't work. I also looked in the WP admin dashboard to see if there was something I could click to force the page to be considered an archive.

Edit: To be clear, I'm looking for a WP solution. I know that I can hard-code the CSS to get the menu item to appear the way I want it to be, but that doesn't seem to be the right thing to do.

Comment: Is all your bothered about is showing the blog tab being highlighted, when on an archive page?

Comment: Yes. This is all I am bothered about. I suppose a simple way to rephrase this is that my custom-template page isn't recognized as an archive page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the change in the question, the answer to this is:

1. Look at the css classes that are applied to the menu-item of interest.
2. The menu-item which this page should be a child of should have `current-page-ancestor` applied to it.
3. Make the appropriate changes in your styling sheet to style the menu when this class appears.

Answer (score 1):

The `archives.php` template file is a custom page template file for a *static Page*. The `is_archive()` and `is_home()` conditionals apply to a *blog posts archive* and *blog posts index*, respectively.So, you're **never** going to get `is_archive()` to return true while displaying the output of `archives.php`.

To have your `archives.php` *static Page* appear in the menu:

1. Create a new static Page, named whatever, e.g. "Archives" (but it is completely arbitrary)
2. Assign the `archives.php` custom Page template to this static Page
3. Add this static Page to your custom Nav Menu

Then, you should see it highlighting properly in the menu.

Comment: I don't need the static page to appear in the menu. I need the menu item 'Blog' to be highlighted. Perhaps I need to hook into the menu code for this? I'll clarify in my question this point... I'm communicating poorly. :(

Answer (score 0):

> Is all your bothered about is showing
>   the blog tab being highlighted, when
>   on an archive page? – Alex Thomas 38
>   mins ago

---

> Yes. This is all I am bothered about.
>   I suppose a simple way to rephrase
>   this is that my custom-template page
>   isn't recognized as an archive page. –
>   Avry 18 mins ago

If this is the case you could be a little crude and just set the style of the blog tab in your archives.php template, using either `<style>...</style>` or give the blog tab the selected class using jquery:

```
$('#blogtabid').addClass('selectedclass');
```

How about that?

Comment: Umm. I suppose that works. I'm looking for a WP answer, though. This seems like something WP should be able to do. Further, if I change my menu this change won't stick.

Comment: true, very true...

Answer (score 0):

You're right to go to the `$wp_query` object.

`$wp_query->is_archive = true;`

Comment: I still don't think this is a good approach. Overriding core conditionals like that can (and almost certainly will) have unintended consequences.

Comment: @Avry: I would give it a whirl. Of course, no checkmark for me if there are consequences!

Comment: Is `$wp_query->is_archive = true;` different from `$wp_query->set('is_archive', 1);`? I've tried this with no results. Where should I put this? (See the question content for details).

Answer (score 0):

I came across something like this recently for highlighting terms if single post is active and to be honest i had to use some jquery for it. Its not pretty but it works for now. Wordpress lacks this feature which i do agree **sucks** You can always use a function to load it for certain pages.

**Example:**

```
function wpse_20163_navstyle() {
    if(is_archive()) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#blogtabid').addClass('selectedclass');
        });
        </script>
    <? }
add_action('wp_head','wpse_20163_navstyle')
```

Also if you are wanting to use the `$wp_query` make sure to have a global as well

`global $wp_query;` and then you can `$wp_query->is_archive = true;`